# Referencing values from an array in java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When splitting a simple array using Java, how can I reference the specific values without using println?

I have a string separated by `"||"` - I want to manipulate that string such that I can call each half of it and assign each bit to a new string. If this was php I'd use list() or explode(), but I can't seem to get the variables to work.

I want to

1. output the contents of each half of the temp array to the screen and
2. join the portions together as `message = temp[0]+ "-"+ temp[1];` doesn't seem to work.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
             if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
             getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
           }
    Intent intent = getIntent();       
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.SENTMESSAGE);

    //The string is (correctly) submitted in the format foo||bar
    String delimiter = "||";
    String[] temp = message.split(delimiter);

    //??? How do I output temp[0] and temp[1] to the screen without using println?

    //This gives me a single character from one of the variables e.g. f-
    for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++)
    message = temp[0]+ "-"+ temp[1];

    //if I escape the above 2 lines this shows foo||bar to the eclipse screen
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView); 
}
```

Comment: _"How do I output temp[0] and temp[1] to the screen without using println"_ seriously without using `println`? maybe use `print`, `printf`, `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`, etc?

Comment: Eclipse said there was an error when I use System.out.println() as it is in a void class.

Comment: Why did you put it as single `String` instead of e.g. [`Intent#putStringArrayListExtra(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putStringArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At fist glance it seems that your problem is here

```
String delimiter = "||";
String[] temp = message.split(delimiter);
```

because `split` uses regex as parameter and in regex `|` is special character representing `OR`. So  with `||` you split on: empty String `""` OR empty string `""` OR empty String `""`.
Since empty String is always before each character and after character result of split such as `"abc".split("||")` will be `["", "a", "b", "c"]` (last empty Strings by default removed are removed from result array).

To solve this problem you will have to escape `|`. You can do it by placing `\` (which in Java needs to be written as `"\\"`) before this metacharacter or you can just use `Pattern.quote(regex)` to escape all `regex` metacharacters for you. Try

```
String delimiter = "||";
String[] temp = message.split(Pattern.quote(delimiter));
```

Comment: Ahhhh. Thank you so much. I thought I was going mad.